# return a specific value from ajax get

Tags: jquery

I know there is a topic that covers this ([How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)) but I do not understand it...

What i'm trying todo is get a specific value for each variable i specify from my getInfo function:

```
var colour = getInfo(schedule.schedule_id, 'colour');
var date = getInfo(schedule.schedule_id, 'date');

function getInfo(scheduleid, action) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?schedule_id='+scheduleid,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            successCallback(data, action);
        },
        async: false
    });
}

function successCallback(data, action){
    return data.action;
   }
```

i get undefined....

*EDIT*
How can i return an array from the ajax data so I can use it like var[1], or var[2]..etc
??

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.  Instead, you need to understand promises.

Comment: @SLaks can you show me an example of how this would work?

Comment: Why are you making two AJAX calls? Why can't you just return one object that has all the data you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @code-jaff i already stated that.... i dont understand though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var colour, date;

function getInfo(scheduleid) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?schedule_id='+scheduleid,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
            colour = data.colour;
            date = data.date;
        }
    });
}
```

And your PHP file needs to return something like this:

```
{ colour: 'red', date: '10-31-2014' }
```

Comment: Your comment was right about returning one object instead of making multiple ajax calls.. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return data[action]` instead of `return data.action`